# Remotely monitor network traffic of servers

Tags: centos, monitoring, network-interface, bandwidth, traffic

Is it possible to remotely monitor network traffic of a server or more and log their result if necessary?

The reason why I'm looking for a tool to capture my servers' network traffic, is that I was somehow disappointed in Icinga 2, and I'd be dead pleased if anyone can let me know if I have any other option.

Comment: Monitor with an eye to what? Your switches might be able to mirror all traffic, or just netflow data, to a different port, but that is massive overkill if you just want to know when the interface is at 100%.

Comment: for raw bandwidth, google observium...it wont capture the traffic tough. If you are more interested on that part, I do recommend you expand and improve your question.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Thanks you so much, I installed it on my machine and it's working perfectly. It'd be great if you provide your solution as an answer so I can check it as "answered" and people can take benefit from it. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro BTW, I guess the latest version captures the traffic.

Answer (score 2):

You can use cacti to monitor a remote server. Icinga/nagios is used to monitor services and connectivity.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I installed Cacti but as @RuiFRibeiro suggested, I also installed Observium and that's providing all data I was looking for. So I go for Observium. Up-voted for your help (+1), thanks.